# react Child component not receiving props

Tags: reactjs, state

This is parent component:

```
class App extends Component {

defaultState = {
    test: "hello"
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = this.defaultState
}

render() {
    return (
    <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route key="home" path="/" test={this.state.test} component={HomeScreen}/>

            </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
}
}
```

and this is the child component:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component{

 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>


            <p>Hello, Welcome to the app. {this.props.test}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

The prop `test` is not printed as in the child component.

What could be the issue?, have been on this for long

Comment: Try this `this.props.route.test`.

Comment: @VipulSingh that fails

Comment: Try adding `defaultProps = {
 propName: propValue,
 ...
};`
in the child component.

Comment: You gotta use the render prop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use render function in

Example:

```
<Route path="/abc" render={()=><TestWidget num="2" someProp={100}/>}/>
```

[Checkout this doc on render function](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

Your render function should look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
    <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route key="home" path="/" render={(props) => <HomeScreen test={this.state.test} {...props} />}/>    
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
}
```