# react routing using RouteComponentProps and custom props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Getting crazy about this issue I have..

Firstly, I am still new to React, secondly, before posting, I tried:
[Passing custom props to router component in react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255415/passing-custom-props-to-router-component-in-react-router-v4)
and 
[react Child component not receiving props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346237/react-child-component-not-receiving-props?noredirect=1&lq=1)

But no luck..

what I am trying to achieve, is simply add routing to existing React project.

For example  top (father) class looks like this:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RouteProps } from "react-router";
import { IAppSettings, IAppConfig, IDataAccess } from "../interfaces";
import { AppConfig } from "../appconfig";
import { DataAccess } from "../DataAccess";
import { BookingSiteOverview } from "./BookingSiteOverview";

import { Layout } from "./Layout";
import { NavigationMenu } from "./NavigationMenu";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

    export class CJV extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, {}> {
        private appConfig: IAppConfig;
        private dataAccess: IDataAccess;

        constructor() {
            super();

        const config: IAppSettings = require("Config");

        AppConfig.apiUrl = config.ApiUrl;

        this.appConfig = new AppConfig();
        this.dataAccess = new DataAccess(this.appConfig);
        this.dataAccess.getProfiles = this.dataAccess.getProfiles.bind(this);
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            <Layout>
                <NavigationMenu />

                <Switch>
                    <Redirect exact={true} from="/" to="/BookingSiteOverview" />
                    <Route path="/BookingSiteOverview" exact render={(props) =>
                        (<BookingSiteOverview getProfiles={this.dataAccess.getProfiles} {...props} />)} />
                </Switch>


 </Layout>;
        </div>;
    }
```

NOTE: error is at `getProfiles={this.dataAccess.getProfiles}`
**Property 'getProfiles' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly>'.**

Child class:

```
 import * as React from "react";
import { ProgressSpinner } from "primereact/components/progressspinner/ProgressSpinner";
import { RouteComponentProps } from "react-router-dom";

import { IBookingSiteOverviewState, IBookingSiteOverviewProps } from "../interfaces";
import { ProfileSelection } from "./ProfileSelection";
import { DateRangeSelection } from "./DateRangeSelection";
import { CollectionStatsTable } from "./CollectionStatsTable";
import { IBookingSiteCollectionStat, ICollectionStatHiddenColumnDefinition } from "../models";

export class BookingSiteOverview extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IBookingSiteOverviewState> {
    private stats?: IBookingSiteCollectionStat[];

    constructor(props: IBookingSiteOverviewProps) {
        super();

    this.state = { statsLoading: false, applyButtonPressed: false };
}

public render() {
    const statsTable = this.state.statsLoading
        ? <ProgressSpinner />
        : <CollectionStatsTable
            id="booking-site-stats"
          getRowDefinition={this.props.getProfiles} 
//<---- Displays error:     Property 'getProfiles' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<RouteComponentProps<{}>>'.

            stats={this.stats}
            statKey="bookingSiteId"
            rowExpansionTemplate={this.props.getProfiles}
            tableWidth="1341px" />;

    const statsSection = this.state.applyButtonPressed ? statsTable : "";

    return <div>
        {statsTable}
    </div>;
}
```

}

So I cannot figure out, how to pass  custom props, and react routing props, so routing would work, and child class receives its properties..

Comment: `interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
  getProfiles: any;
}`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A React component in Typescript is defined like this:

`class ComponentName extends React.Component<PropsType, StateType> { ... }`

In this case BookingSiteOverview accepts props of type RouteComponentProps<{}> and uses a state of type IBookingSiteOverviewState.

RouteComponentProps<{}> does not include a definition for getProfiles, so that is causing the errors.

**EDIT**

getProfiles is defined in IBookingSiteOverviewProps (per the OP) so changing the props for BookingSiteOverview to `RouteComponentProps<{}> & IBookingSiteOverviewProps` resolves the issue:

```
export class BookingSiteOverview extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}> & IBookingSiteOverviewProps, IBookingSiteOverviewState> {
    constructor(props: RouteComponentProps<{}> & IBookingSiteOverviewProps) {
        super(props);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: The constructor for BookingSiteOverview accepts props of type IBookingSiteOverviewProps, is it possible you just forgot to use that interface for the props type of the component?

Comment: Sorry for late response, I did solved this, just forgot to update  stackOverflow.. 

If I understood everything correctly  react routing needs RouteComponentProps<{}> and my component need IBookingSiteOverviewProps, what  simply worked.. 
 inside component just `React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}> & IBookingSiteOverviewProps`

And when calling my BookingSiteOverview component, just additionally to it's props, pass {...props} for routing.