# Go up one level in React-Router using Link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Surprisingly that it's been kind of hard to find in Google and in StackOverflow, I'm asking here what's the most efficient way on going up one level in React Router using `<Link>`?

For example I land in this path: `/subject/add`. Then I want to go to `/subject` from `/subject/add`.

This works:

```
<Link to={props.match.url.substring(0, props.match.url.lastIndexOf('/'))}>
Go up one level </Link>
```

Is it the best way to do it? (Note: `history.goBack` could potentially kick out the user from the website if he arrived on a nested route as his landing page.

Comment: I think that you can use the push('/subject') method to achieve that.

Comment: If you want to have the exact same `<Link>` that will go "up a level" no matter where it is then I think your method is fine.

Comment: sorry for the silly question but what's that "props" that you are referring in your Link component? because I'm getting 'not defined' error.

Comment: @Shayande Props would be the RouteComponentProps that comes from the component's props. In case of React-Router check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51523211/react-routing-using-routecomponentprops-and-custom-props

Answer (score 10):

If somebody still needs it - there is a solution from authors: You can use "." or ".." in your Link component to go one or two levels up.

```
<Link to=".">
```

or

```
history.push(".");
```

Comment: Thank you. is it possible to use this method in the same way as HTML paths

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
<Link to=".." relative="path">
```

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#relative

Comment: Nice, this could be the updated version!

Comment: I think this is a better solution than the previous